How to escape repair mode in laptop after hard restart
When I first open my laptop, At first I press sign in button on screen, it display error "the instruction at xxx referenced memory xxx. The required data was not placed into memory because of an I/O error status of xxx". Then I follow chatGPT trouble shoot guide (I hard restart, it enter repair mode,  I type some command to repair in cmd, as it doesn't work, I reset my laptop. But it still not work). Now my screen is blue and it said "automatic repair couldn't repair my PC". Please help me. 

Your question is off-topic.  Ask it on SuperUser.com.  Or take your laptop to someone who knows how to repair broken Windows computers.
